# Routing 404 not found issue

Tags: node.js, angular

I am running a Express application with Node in the backend. I have 2 functions in a component in NodeJS which I am trying to access from my service. The link for both are the same in the service. It is able to connect one of the functions from the service.

However, it is showing `404 not found` for accessing the second function in the same component.

Has anyone faced any such issue and if so how can it be rectified?

EDITED :

Some code for reference :

**component1.component.ts**

```
getallprojectcat()
{

this.authenticationService.getprojectcat()
.pipe(first())
.subscribe(

data => {
    this.data = data;
},

error => {

          this.loading = false;
 });
}

}
```

**component2.component.ts**

```
showprojects(moid)
{
this.authenticationService.getprojectslist(moid)
.pipe(first())
.subscribe(
data => {
    this.silver = data;
},
error => {
    console.log('some error');      
    this.alertService.error(error);
    this.loading = false;
 });
}
```

**the .service file**

```
getprojectcat() 
{
 return this.http.get<any>(this.studenturl+'/getprojectcata/')
.pipe(map(allprojectcat => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(allprojectcat));
    return allprojectcat;
}));
}

getprojectslist(moid) 
{
return this.http.get(this.studenturl+'/getprojects/'+moid)
.pipe(map(projectslist => {
    console.log("Projects List:"+JSON.stringify(projectslist));
    return projectslist;
})).catch(this.handleError);
}
```

**Backend .js file**

```
exports.getprojectcata = function(req, res){
     console.log("First Function");

};
exports.getprojects = function(req, res){
    console.log("Second Function");

};
```

The function getprojectcata is working in the first component. However, it shows an 404 not found on the getprojects function in the second component. I have checked the following things -

1. Routing does not seem to be the problem as it is moving to the next component without any issues.
2. We have also tried calling the getprojectscata through the same service in component and it worked.

Comment: You should first determinate which one is failing your backend or frontend, maybe you can use curl or something like that to test your backend service response

Comment: Some code would be useful to understand better what's going on.

Comment: hi jacopro. I have added the code in question. Please let me know. Thanks